# How to make a movie with transparent background in a flash with transparent background

Tags: flash, actionscript, movieclip, mask, movie

I want to make a flash like the one here http://www.multisoft.com/ (wait for the page to load). The nice lady in the bottom right of the page has a transparent background. I'm not interested in background of the flash (not the wmode stuff), but in the background of the movie itself. Is there an easy way to do that? Maybe a script that takes a color from every frame and makes a mask out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking but it looks like the lady on the linked site is just a alpha channel flv (very much like [this](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/talking_head_video_05.html).) That's accomplished in the encoding process for the video and not in actionscript...are you looking for a programmatic way to do that?